# load images into cache and display into UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

how can i display image into `UICollectionView` using Cache and display large image into another
View on `UICollectionView` didSelect. Here both large and thumb image on CollectionView so next view large image not blank.using EMAsyncImageView

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://leewayinfotech.com/mobile/girlwallpaper/api.php?category=abstract&device=i5&hits=all"];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:req queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //NSLog(@"Response String=%@",responseString);
    NSError *jsonError;
    NSData *trimmedData = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:trimmedData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&jsonError];

    if (jsonError) {
        NSLog(@"JSON parse error: %@", jsonError);
        return;
    }

    obj_Array=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    obj_Array=[json objectForKey:@"wallpaper"];

    //NSMutableArray *tmp = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[obj_Array count]];
    imgPage.thumb_img_Array=[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[obj_Array count]];
    imgPage.device_img_Array=[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[obj_Array count]];
    imgPage.imgNo_Array=[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[obj_Array count]];

    for (int i=0; i<[obj_Array count]; i++) {
        ImgClass *obj_Class=[[ImgClass alloc] init];
        obj_Class.main_id=[[[obj_Array objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"id"] integerValue];

        [obj_Class.thumb_img_Array addObject:[[[obj_Array objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"images"] objectForKey:@"image_thumb"]];
        [obj_Class.device_img_Array addObject:[[[obj_Array objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"images"] objectForKey:@"image2"]];
         NSLog(@"Thumb-->%@\n\nDevice-->%@",[obj_Class.thumb_img_Array description],[obj_Class.device_img_Array description]);
        [appDelg.my_Array addObject:obj_Class];
    }
```

Comment: @Montu..Are you using SDWebImage for loading images. Put some code what you wrote for setting image.

Answer (score 0):

you use the [EGOImageView](https://github.com/enormego/EGOImageLoading) for image caching support.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SDWebImage.Using SDWebImage you can set image using imageURLString like below with CacheType.

```
[yourImgView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURLString]
                       placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"noimage.png"]
                              completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType)
         {
             if (!error && image)
             {

             }
         }];
```

Hope it will helps you..